# Webpage not available MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, relational-database

My application was working fine until I added 3 new classes(Administrator,Department and Depot) and altered the IssueContext.cs in the Data Access Layer.
Since my IssueContext has been altered I needed to update my database so I used `update-database` in the Package Manager Console then I got this(Open tab in the new window)
[image]

Which is weird because it was working perfectly fine before. I then installed Entity Framework then update-database worked.
However when I click on my User tabs or About tabs they give me a "Webpage not available" but the Index page works. Could this be a relational database mapping problem where I didn't map my new classes correctly?

Note: I also tried installing MVC but MVC Razor just crashes everything.

[image]

Here's my Entity Diagram
[image]

User.cs

```
public class User
{

    public int UserID { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "First name cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]

    [Column("FirstName")]
    public string FirstMidName { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }

    public string FullName
    {
        get { return LastName + ", " + FirstMidName; }
    }
    public int AdministratorID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AdministratorID")]
    public virtual Administrator Administrator { get; set; }

    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DepartmentID")]
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }


    public int DepotID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DepotID")]
    public virtual Depot Depot { get; set; }

    public int TicketID { get; set; }
    //Setting up relationships A use can apply for any number of tickets, so Tickets is defined as a collection of Ticket entities.
    public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Users { get; set; }

}
```

Ticket.cs

```
public class Ticket
{
    public string Issue { get; set; } 
    [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "No Priority")]
    public Priority? Priority { get; set; }
    //Category One to Many Ticket
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CategoryID")]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    //User (One to Many) Ticket
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public int TicketID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TicketID")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public int AdminID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Administrator> Administrators { get; set; }

}
```

Depot.cs

```
public class Depot
{
    public int DepotID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }

}
```

Department.cs

```
public class Department
{
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Category.cs

```
public class Category
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
}
```

Administrator.cs

```
    public class Administrator
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public int AdminID { get; set; }
    public int TicketID { get; set; }        
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string AdminRole { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Context.cs

```
public class IssueContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Administrator> Administrators { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Depot> Depots { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Ticket>()
            .HasMany(c => c.Administrators).WithMany(i => i.Tickets)
            .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("TicketID")
                .MapRightKey("AdministratorID")
                .ToTable("AdministratorsTickets"));


        modelBuilder.Entity<Administrator>()
                   .HasKey(e => e.UserID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasOptional(s => s.Administrator) // Mark StudentAddress is optional for Student
            .WithRequired(ad => ad.User); // Create inverse relationship


        }
    }
```

Comment: "ERROR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" is not likely a code issue. There was no socket on the server even listening for requests. It's likely that your web server is completely stopped, or a firewall started blocking the requests, etc/

Comment: I ran a few code in the VS2012 Native tool command prompt. `sqllocaldb.exe stop v11.0` and `sqllocaldb.exe delete v11.0` Is there a command to restart it? I'm pretty sure it's not related to firewall.